# Nested aggregate functions in Django

Tags: django, annotations

I have the following models

```
class Domain(models.Model):
    domain = models.URLField()
    web_analytics = models.ManyToManyField('AnalyticsProvider', blank=True)

class AnalyticsProvider(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

I want to get the number of analytics per domain and them aggregate them by number of analytics. I want to get a result like:
{ "1 analytics provider": "520 domains",
  "2 analytics provider": "130 domains",
...}

. I manage to do it with an SQL query, but I want to use the django ORM, the SQL query is the following:

```
SELECT COUNT(1),"num_m2m" from (SELECT "dashboard_domain"."id_website", COUNT("dashboard_domain_web_analytics"."analyticsprovider_id") AS "num_m2m" 
FROM "dashboard_domain" LEFT OUTER JOIN "dashboard_domain_web_analytics" 
ON ("dashboard_domain"."id_website" = "dashboard_domain_web_analytics"."domain_id") 
GROUP BY "dashboard_domain"."id_website") GROUP BY "num_m2m";
```

I tried to do a double annotate in the queryset like:

```
    number_web_analytics = Domain.objects.annotate(num_m2m=Count('web_analytics')).annotate(count_domains=Count('num_m2m'))
```

But seems like django cannot do an annotation on another one.

Answer (score 0):

You say you want number of analytics per domain.

So, why not only one annotation:

```
number_web_analytics = Domain.objects.annotate(num_m2m=Count('web_analytics'))
```

And you can get number of analytics for first domian as:

```
number_web_analytics[0].num_m2m
```

Comment: Sorry, I problably don't explain it well. This is what I have, now I want to group the domains by number of analytics.

Answer (score 0):

The ORM gets really convoluted with complex queries. If you can't figure it out, you can always simply execute raw sql like so:

```
>>> for p in Person.objects.raw('SELECT * FROM myapp_person'):
...     print(p)
John Smith
Jane Jones
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/.

Comment: I know but I was planning to reuse the query for different models. I guess this is the only way to do it. Thanks for your response.

Comment: Using raw queries is the worst idea ever. It would cause more serious issues in the future.